# How can I have two stores of the same SwiftData model?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I have this simple model:

```swift
@Model
class BasicTrainInfo {
    @Attribute(.unique) let number: String
    @Attribute(.unique) let technicalNumber: String
    
    init(number: String, technicalNumber: String) {
        self.number = number
        self.technicalNumber = technicalNumber
    }
}
```

I know I can create a model container using `ModelContainer(for: [Schema])` and then query the information stored for that schema with the `@Query` macro.

But I cannot find the way to have **two different** stores for the same type. In my case, I want to store the trains the user has favorited and the 10 most recent trains whose info the user has viewed.

In my mind I would have a store for the favorite trains and a store for the recent trains, but I don't know how to do this.

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: This is not something you have a second store for, add another model for keeping track of the favourites. Recent viewed could just be a date property on the existing model or another model or even perhaps something to store in UserDefaults

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But wouldn't it be redundant to have another model for the exact same information?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Also, maybe this is not the best case to have a second store, but I think the question is still relevant as of how to do it...? Have not found any clear information.

Comment: It wouldn't be redundant since it would contain a relationship to the train model instead of containing the exact same information

Comment: Create a second ModelContainer using a ModelConfiguration that defines the name (and url) of the second store.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried creating it that way and specified a new url, but it crashed, complaining that the file could not be found. Also, not sure how would I query that ModelContainer.

Comment: Skip the url parameter then, its probably only to be used when you have an existing store you want to use.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried that but did not work. The app would crash. It would appear then as I had two stores for the same type with nothing to distinguish them?

Comment: Well you need to experiment some more, I don’t know what your code looks like or why it crashed