# How can I use the same Model in SwiftData for two different ModelContainers?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-data

I want to implement a trashcan for my app.
Using a very simple model I want to store to active items in one ModelContainer and the deleted ones in another.

In order to access the containers I wrote a singleton.

```swift
import SwiftData

class DataHolder {
    static let sharedInstance = DataHolder()
    
    let activeContainer:ModelContainer
    let trashContainer:ModelContainer

    
    private init() {
        
        let schema = Schema([Song.self])
        let storeURL = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "active.sqlite")
        let config = ModelConfiguration(url: storeURL)
        let container = try! ModelContainer(for:schema, configurations: config)
        self.activeContainer = container;
        
        
        let schemaTrash = Schema([Song.self])
        let storeURLTrash = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "trash.sqlite")
        let configTrash = ModelConfiguration(url: storeURLTrash)
        let containerTrash = try! ModelContainer(for:schemaTrash, configurations: configTrash)
        self.trashContainer = containerTrash;
        
        print("init datamodel")
       
    }
    
}
```

But when I try to save the active ContainerModel the App crashes.

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134020 "The model configuration used to open the store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the store."
```

I tried to add naming and change the storage location but nothing works. Is there a different approach to implement such a feature?

I'm aware of [How can I have two stores of the same SwiftData model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875553/how-can-i-have-two-stores-of-the-same-swiftdata-model). But the proposed solution doesn't work in my case.

Edit:

The app crashed after inserting a new item:

```swift
Task {
        let newSong = Song();
        await DataHolder.sharedInstance.activeContainer.mainContext.insert(newSong)
       try! await DataHolder.sharedInstance.activeContainer.mainContext.save()
}
```

Comment: You can’t, you can use protocols. The model tells swift data where to save, if it is in 2 containers it doesn’t know what to pick.

Comment: What did you do more exactly when it crashed, could you create a reproducible example or at least add some code/explanation that is relative?

Comment: You mean combining trashed items and active items in one database? And then sorting out all trashed items, when displaying them normally?

Comment: Not directly addressing your question: why are you disabling error propagation? Use `do-try-catch` to get the failure reason.

Comment: Your right @soundflix. Thanks for the advice. I just wanted to do a quick POC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what to tried to do is not possible with SwiftData. In order to differentiate between deleted items and active items I use a boolean flag in my model. Thereby I can sort them out in the @Query wrapper.